# Getting a LocalDate out of an avro GenericRecord in Java

Tags: java, deserialization, avro

I have written a class, `AvroIterator<T>`, that is a small wrapper around some avro calls, allowing the user to specify a filename, schema filename, and a method to get a `T` from an avro `GenericRecord`.

This works fine with primitive types. For example, in my tests I have this class:

```java
public class TripleData {
    private final int x;
    private final double y;
    private final String z;

    public TripleData(int x, double y, String z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

static TripleData getTripleData(GenericRecord record) {
    return new TripleData(
            (int)record.get("x"),
            (double)record.get("y"),
            ((CharSequence)record.get("z")).toString()
    );
}
```

and I get an iterator as follows:

```java
Iterator<TripleData> iterator = new AvroIterator<>(TRIPLE_DATA_FILENAME_1,
                                                   TRIPLE_DATA_SCHEMA_FILENAME,
                                                   AvroIteratorTest::getTripleData);
```

The problem arises when I want to deserialize a class containing a logical type. Currently I'm trying to do date.

```java
private static class DatedData {
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final double x;
    private final int y;

    private DatedData(LocalDate date, double x, int y) {
        this.date = date;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

My schema is

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "DatedData",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "date", "type": "int"},
    {"name": "x", "type": "double"},
    {"name": "y", "type": "int"}
  ]
}
```

When I try to write an equivalent `getDatedData(GenericRecord record)` method, I cannot follow the same pattern as for `TripleData`. If I call `(LocalDate)record.get("date")`, a `ClassCastException` gets thrown, since that `record.get` call returns an `int`.

I don't want to just use a call to `LocalDate.ofEpochDay`, since then I'm depending on the avro documentation on how to convert from the primitive type to the logical type, and there is no checking that the schema genuinely defines this field to be a date.

It looks like the 'correct' thing to do create an instance of avro's `TimeConversions.DateConversion` class, and call its `fromInt` method to make my conversion. This has the signature

```java
public LocalDate fromInt(Integer daysFromEpoch, Schema schema, LogicalType type)
```

I therefore added an inner class `Converter` to `DatedData`, which would hold the `Schema`, and have a conversion method:

```java
public static class Converter {
    private final Schema schema;
    private final LogicalType dateLogicalType;
    private final TimeConversions.DateConversion innerConverter;

    Converter(Schema schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
        this.dateLogicalType = schema.getField("date").schema().getLogicalType();
        innerConverter = new TimeConversions.DateConversion();
    }
    Converter(String schemaFilename) throws IOException {
        this(new Schema.Parser().parse(new File(schemaFilename)));
    }

    public DatedData getFromGenericRecord(GenericRecord record) {
        LocalDate date = innerConverter.fromInt((int)record.get("date"), schema, dateLogicalType);
        return new DatedData(
                date,
                (double)record.get("x"),
                (int)record.get("y")
        );
    }
}
```

I then create my iterator as follows:

```java
Iterator<DatedData> iterator = new AvroIterator<>(DATED_DATA_FILENAME,
                                                  DATED_DATA_SCHEMA_FILENAME,
                                                  new DatedData.Converter(DATED_DATA_SCHEMA_FILENAME)::getFromGenericRecord);
```

This works, **but** it still works if I replace the `Schema` and `LogicalType` in the `fromInt` call with `null`. It also still works if I modify my schema to make "date" just have type `int`. i.e. I get no verification of the schema with this method.

What I hoped to gain from this is some sort of failure if I was trying to convert something that was not really serialized as a date, and some protection in case avro ever change the definition of how a date is serialized. Also, I would like for anyone reading the code to be able to say "ok, clearly this uses Avro's method to deserialize a date, I don't have to go and read the avro docs."

Is there something better that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the logical type to your schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "DatedData",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "date", "type": { "type": "int", "logicalType": "date"} },
    {"name": "x", "type": "double"},
    {"name": "y", "type": "int"}
  ]
}
```